# Не работает путь файла ErrorDocument

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, веб-сервер

Привет всем! У меня проблема: в файле `.htaccess` не работает путь к следующим параметрам:

`ErrorDocument 301`,
`ErrorDocument 302` ,
`ErrorDocument 400` ,
`ErrorDocument 403`,
`ErrorDocument 404`,
`ErrorDocument 500`,

Путь указываю относительный – `errors/undefined`. Добавлял параметр `RewriteBase /` – не помог. Когда в адресной строке пишешь файл, которого нет (например `a` когда включен `Options +MultiViews` или `a.php`) пишет: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ином же случае:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но все равно документ не выводит – выводит просто текст. Работает только если путь будет таким: `localhost/en/errors/undefined`

Comment: `RewriteBase` - это для `RewriteEngine`. Для ошибок надо полный путь

Comment: @DNS То есть так и писать: http://localhost/en/errors/undefined ?

Comment: @DNS Ну ладно, все равно значения не имеет :) . Я просто на смартфоне по ссылке http://192.168.0.101/ (иногда http://192.168.0.100/ или http://192.168.0.102/ ) сайт тестил а так мне это неважно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Путь указываю относительный – errors/undefined

А надо либо абсолютный либо относительно корня (documentroot) сайта. И файл с расширением.
Напр:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/undefined.php
```

Comment: При вашем варианте: https://ibb.co/bESeyv

Comment: А хотя нет, От корня сервера работает.